# How do I modify the database field that changes taxes on magento 1 for all products?

Tags: mysql, magento

I want to edit this fild and add instead of `"none"` to be `"tva"` but for all products.

[link](https://www.screencast.com/t/Rnoy2DMu6)

I have about 3000 products and I want to do this automatically.

Can you do this with a query in `phpmyadmnin`?

What is the table where these values are saved?

Comment: TVA is synonymous VAT

Answer (score 0):

Go to Catalog->Products, in table that display product choose "Select All" and then go to "Actions" and choose update "Update Attributes" and click "Submit". Then set Tax class value from selectbox.